# Hide block if no submenu in Twig

Tags: twig, drupal-8, theming

In Drupal-8. I'm creating a node--page.html.twig and I'm using twig_tweak to help render a block for my sidebar to display Level-3 links on my menu. Currently, most of my pages are displaying correctly because most of them have level-3 submenus.

Unfortunately, Some pages that don't have any level-3 submenus are still rendering the title and div tags and I'm not sure why.

Here's an image of what it looks like for pages that has no level-3 submenus:

[image]

Here's my snippet of code on how I'm rendering the sidebar in my node--page.html.twig file:

```
  {% set submenu = drupal_entity('block', 'mainmenu', check_access=false)|render %} 
  {% if submenu %}
    <div class="page-sidebar grid-3 alpha">
     <div class="sub-region page-sidebar clearfix widgets widget-sidebar">
      <div class="contextual-links-region panel-pane pane-menu-tree pane-main-menu">
        {{ submenu }}
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
```

Here's an image of the Block settings of my menu levels to display level-3 links:
[image]

In Twig, is there a way to hide my left sidebar completely if there are no level-3 submenus for the page?

Thank you!

Comment: Found a patch created by Stef Van Looveren in this post: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/262100/99182